# IRS form for Advance Child Tax Credit (CTC) Opt-Out

Tags: united-states, irs, tax-credit, children

Aside from the User-Portal on IRS Web Site, what other methods are available to opt-out of the 2021 Advance Child Tax Credit?

I'm specifically thinking of an IRS Paper Form akin to all their other available tax forms.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Question A5](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/2021-child-tax-credit-and-advance-child-tax-credit-payments-topic-a-general-information) of the IRS' [2021 Child Tax Credit and Advance Child Tax Credit Payments FAQ](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/2021-child-tax-credit-and-advance-child-tax-credit-payments-frequently-asked-questions):

> **Q A5. What if I do not want to receive advance Child Tax Credit payments? (added June 14, 2021)**
>
> A5. If you prefer not to receive monthly advance Child Tax Credit payments because you would rather claim the full credit when you file your 2021 tax return, or you know you will not be eligible for the Child Tax Credit for your 2021 tax year, you will be able to unenroll through the Child Tax Credit Update Portal (CTC UP). CTC UP will be available in June and will allow you to unenroll before the first advance Child Tax Credit payment is made. You will not be able to unenroll before the portal is open.
>
> For more information regarding CTC UP, see [Topic F: Updating Your Child Tax Credit Information During 2021](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/2021-child-tax-credit-and-advance-child-tax-credit-payments-topic-f-updating-your-child-tax-credit-information-during-2021).

Following that link to Topic F, Question F4 says:

> **Q F4. What do I need to do to unenroll myself from receiving advance Child Tax Credit payments? (added June 14, 2021)**
>
> A4. The Child Tax Credit Update Portal (CTC UP) will allow you to unenroll from receiving advance Child Tax Credit payments. More details will be provided regarding CTC UP through these questions and answers once the portal is available.

At this time, the Portal does not yet appear to be operational, and there has been no indication of any method of opting-out by mail.